# How to execute multiple stored procedures at a time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to know that is there any way through which I can execute all my stored procedure at a time.
Presently I am executing each stored procedure using `exec "Stored Procedure name"` command.
And I have more than 200 stored procedure to be executed on my database.

Is there any easy way out to execute all these stored procedure at a single time as it is difficult for me to keep a track of them?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you write a stored procedure which calls the other ones.

Answer (score 4):

Put all stored procedures inside a stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CallAllProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    CALL Proc1
    CALL Proc2
END
```

Comment: how to wait end of Proc1 and then start Proc2?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using Query Analyzer, just put a GO in between all those stored proc and run script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute them all in parallel you could create a SQLJob and schedule them all to execute at the same time.  Link below is general usage of SQL Jobs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can select all stored procedure names from sys.objects table querying type='P'. After you can use cursor for every stored procedure name to execute. But how about stored procedures with parameters? you must provide parameter values as well to avoid from errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service broker to do this async but I dont think it is a great idea to run 200 stored procs at the same time unless you are sure there will not be any contention on the DB